# Can't display static image in the same folder as the component in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.2

In the directory of my component, I've put an image. It's a good, old, plain PNG with a logotyp. So there are four files in there:

- blobb.png
- blobb.comp.ts
- blobb.comp.html
- blobb.comp.scss

In the HTML file, I used a static source link in a default IMG tag like this.

```
<img src="./blobb.png">
```

I was trying to follow the setup suggested in [this blog](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/552). At the moment, I have no need for dynamic images. The static ones will suffice. My understanding's that assets folder is an option but not required.

There's no error, except for the 404 Not found, of course. The link to the missing file is:

> https://localhost:44385/logo02.png

I'm not sure how to deduce if it's a matter of incorrect link to the image file or if the file isn't accessible. How can I diagnoze it furhter?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: are you using angular cli? you might need to put image in assets folder.

Comment: @Stefan The code is in the question. Static link in IMG tag. There's no mode "code" to it in the HTML markup. And there's no logic neither in the component code. Not sure what code that would be of help. Feel free to advise.

Comment: @alt255 I'm using CLI for generating components and services. The image we're talking about is a static, plain PNG. I prefer not to place it in assets as it makes more sense at the moment to keep it with the component, instead. Are you saying I **have to** use assets directory?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana yes you have to use assets directory for images otherwise bundler won't be able to correctly add the path to image in final bundle.

Comment: Please provide a [example].

Comment: @Trilarion Gladly. Do you have a suggestion on how to do that? The configurations of Webpack aren't that apparent and explicit in a .NET project, as the case is here. I added a tag for that originally but someone removed it without me noticing. The issue is .NET related partially since MS has it's own adaptation of the process. Using StackBlitz won't be possible for instance. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Okay, in this case it probably boils down to exactly describe how you followed the setup described in the blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the image in assets folder and then reference it in your html like this

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png">
```

You need to do this, as the cli compiles and bundles your application it also bundles your assets too and path to image may change during bundling process.

See this [link for an example](https://scotch.io/courses/build-your-first-angular-website/adding-an-imagelogo-in-angular)

Comment: Do you have any idea where it's declared that it's the *assets* folder and not e.g. *donkey* folder that's the target of all included images? I can't find any webpack config files in my solution...

Comment: @DonkeyBanana [see this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md) be aware that it's old and not maintained but still works.